# How to set up diff so that it copies all modified and new files and subfolders recursively from a folder at a given interval?

Tags: linux, shell, diff

How to set up diff so that it copies all modified and new files and subfolders recursively from a folder at a given interval?

Hi,

I have a folder (A) with a large number of subfolders.

I want to write a script using diff or some similar tool that checks the folder (A) recursively at a given interval and moves all new files and folders to another folder (B).

Is diff the right tool for the job and how would the script look like?

Please note: I don't want to use inotifywait.

Also: folder A should be compared to itself at a previous time. Folder A should not be compared to folder B.

Vesa

Comment: Have a look at rsync :)

Comment: Hmm.. I kinda like rsync. Can it copy modified and new files and subfolders only? How?

Comment: I think rsync needs to compare two directories. I was rather thinking of a solution where only modified files and folders are moved to folder B. So folder A being compared to itself at a previous time.

Comment: In spite of the name, rsync is unidirectional... but it will try to replicate the source structure in the destination dir, which means copying all those unchanged files (which you do not want, if I understand you correctly). Hmmm... `find` works recursively, and has some options like `-newer` (newer than another given file, or newer since some timestamp); cf. `man find`. The `find` tool doesn't do copying, but if you can get `find` to list the selection of files you want to copy, you maybe could employ the output of `find` as input file list to `rsync`, `cp`, `scp` or whatever.

Comment: Interesting, I also kept researching today and was just suggested to use find from another source. I will take it into consideration.